# Cannot write to flash memory - STM32L462

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, hal, flash-memory

I'm trying to flash data to my flash memory by parsing the hex file sent over UART. But after erasing the flash, I can't write to it. This is my code:

**Code to erase flash:**

```c
__HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_OPTVERR | FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_OPERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR |
                FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR |FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR);
/* Get the 1st page to erase */
FirstPage = ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_12;
/* Get the number of pages to erase from 1st page */
NbOfPages = 243;
/* Get the bank */
BankNumber = FLASH_BANK_1;

EraseInitStruct.TypeErase   = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
EraseInitStruct.Banks       = BankNumber;
EraseInitStruct.Page        = FirstPage;
EraseInitStruct.NbPages     = NbOfPages;

HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct,&PAGEError);
```

**Code to write flash:**

```c
uint64_t flashData = 0;
uint32_t flashWriteAddress = (extendedAddress | recordAddress | k);
nibbleArrayToUInt64(&data[recordDataOffset],(uint32_t)i); //convert nibble[] to uint64_t and store in flashData
CLEAR_BIT(FLASH->CR, FLASH_CR_PER);
HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD,flashWriteAddress,(uint64_t)flashData);
```

**Code to convert nibble array to uint64_t:**

```c
void nibbleArrayToUInt64(uint8_t* var, uint32_t lowest_pos)
{
    uint8_t byte;
    flashData = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<16;j+=2)
    {
        byte = (((uint64_t)(var[lowest_pos+j]<<4 | var[lowest_pos+j+1])));
        flashData |= (((uint64_t)byte) << (8*(7-(j/2))));
    }
}
```

The error flags triggered are :

```
HAL_FLASH_ERROR_PROG
HAL_FLASH_ERROR_PGA
HAL_FLASH_ERROR_PGS
```

I don't know what mistake I'm doing. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding the errors. Is only *HAL_FLASH_Program* failing and the earlier erase has completed successfully? Will the first write immediately fail? And will it really return any of these error codes? Or is there a specific sequence that leads up to each error code? And the error codes have a meaning: *ERROR_PROG*: the flash at the address has not been erased. *ERROR_PGA*: The write address is not aligned with a double word address. *ERROR_PGS*: The sequence of operations is incorrect, or a previous error has not been cleared.

Comment: Yes. the erase operation is successful. Yes, even the first write fails. Error code is set to 0x42. And for all writes the same error code is set. This is the address of my variable with data in ram `0x0200004a8`. I think it is aligned. The first write address is `0x080006000`. @Codo BTW. Now I'm not getting `HAL_FLASH_ERROR_PROG` , but other 2 I'm still getting. Error code 0x40.

Comment: I could be wrong but most likely the problem is outside the code shown in the question. It's either related to the sequence of operations, address calculation or similar. I'm also confused about the error code? Where do they come from? According to my understanding, 0x42 is a combination of *SIZERR* and *OPERR*, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Nope. 0x42 in my case is the combination of those 3 errors. PGA|PGS|PROG

Comment: 0x42 in binary is `0100 0010`. As it has only two bits sets, it cannot be the combination of three values. Please show more code and show how you derive these error values.

Comment: That issue is solved. There was some issue while erasing the flash. Once that was fixed, It started writing to the flash. The new issue is if I write `F9A7000800800220` , it saves as `200280000800A7F9` . Any solution??

Comment: A core idea of StackOverflow is that it is a growing collection of questions and answers useful for visitor long after the OP's issue has been solved – a concept quite different from a discussion forum. Therefore, please write an answer to your own question that explains the solution, and start a new question for the new issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should unlock the flash before erase or write. For example:

```
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef pEraseInit;
pEraseInit.Banks = 0;
pEraseInit.NbSectors = 1;
pEraseInit.Sector = FLASH_SECTOR_2;
pEraseInit.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_SECTORS;
pEraseInit.VoltageRange = FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3;
uint32_t sectorError;
HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&pEraseInit, &sectorError);
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, VERSION_SAVE_ADDRESS, version);
HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

Comment: I had already unlocked it by creating an init function.

Comment: Try to call unlock function just before erase and write functions.

Comment: Remove the line 'CLEAR_BIT(FLASH->CR, FLASH_CR_PER);' If the problem is still exist change it as SET_BIT.

Comment: `HAL_FLASHEx_Erase` already clears the bits. I fixed the issue. will update later. Thank you for the help.